# Html link loads but doesn't function

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

```
      <!DOCTYPE html> 
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Astro Tools</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>

        <body>

         <div data-role="page">

            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Astrophoto Tools</h1>
            </div>


            <div data-role="content">

                <p>
                    Welcome to Astrophoto Tools. These simple calcualting tools will help you to avoid Star Trials.
                </p>

                <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="basic.html">Basic Tool</a></li>
                <li><a href="adv.html">Advanced Tool</a></li>
                <li><a href="hlp.html">Help</a></li>
                <li><a href="abt.html">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Footer</h4>
            </div>

        </div>

        </body>
        </html>
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Here is the basic.html 
////////////////////////

    <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>
    <title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.css" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#lens").on("keyup", function () {
        var lens = $(this).val();
        //var fullframe = 0;  // initialize the sum to zero
        var fullframe = 600 / lens;
        $('#fullframe').val(fullframe.toFixed(2));
        var apsccanon = 600 / (lens * 1.6);
        $('#apsccanon').val(apsccanon.toFixed(2));
        var apscnikon = 600 / (lens * 1.5);
        $('#apscnikon').val(apscnikon.toFixed(2));
        var apscolympus = 600 / (lens * 2.0);
        $('#apscolympus').val(apscolympus.toFixed(2));

        });
    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body,td,th {
        color: #CCC;
    }
    </style>
    </head>  


    <body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header">
             <h3 style="color:#3CF">Astrophoto Tool</h3>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
          <div align="center" style="color:#0F0">No Star Trails Exposure</div>
          <p align="center" style=" color:#FFFF00">Rule 600 </p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
            <form action="">Lens: Focal  Length (mm)
                <br>
                <input type='text' id='lens' style="color:#FF6"/>
                <br>Full Frame: (Time in Seconds)
                <br>
                <input type='text' id='fullframe' value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly>
                <br>APS-C (Canon): (Time in Seconds)
                <br>
                <input type='text' id='apsccanon'  value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly />
                <br>APS - C (Nikon/Sony/Pentax): (Time in Seconds)
                <br>
                <input type='text' id='apscnikon' value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly />
                <br>APS - C (Olympus/Panasonic): (Time in Seconds)
                 <input type='text' id='apscolympus' value="" style="color:#0F0" readonly />


                <input name="Reset" type="reset" value="Reset">
            </form>
        </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4 style="color:#3CF">&copy; Ranjan Mitra 2015</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

When I run the basic.html it works without a problem but whenever I click the link to basic.html in the index.html the calculations do not work at all. Where am I going wrong? please help.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: jQM loads pages via AJAX by default and only gets the content of the first DIV with data-role="page". So if your scripts in basic.html are not within the page div, they will not be loaded or run. Either move your scripts or tell jQM to not use AJAX loading (you will lose the slick transitions if you go this way).

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `value=""`in your first `<input>`

```
<input type='text' id='lens' ???? style="color:#FF6"/>
                <br>Full Frame: (Time in Seconds)
```

Comment: The value attribute allows one to specify a default value; its absence isn't the problem here.

Comment: Missing value="" has no effect. basic.html runs ok on it's own the problem is when it is called from index.html it seems that jquery calculation script fails to run. Why this should happen is intriguing because the page loads alright but stops running the script.

Comment: @ranjan Read ezanker's comment on your question.